# Are there any public runnable blockchain sharding mechanisms?

Tags: blockchain, sharding

I want to add contrast experiments in my blockchain sharding paper but it is hard to run the public codes on my computer. I choose omniledger and down load its code from github. The link is [text](https://github.com/dedis/student_18_byzcoin). Who have down this job or how can I find some ways to run a blockchain published in the paper?

I tried to run it on my local virtual machine but it doesn't work fine. When I use

```
go mod tidy
```

the terminal prompts me that

```
go: omni/omniledger/service imports
        github.com/coreos/bbolt: github.com/coreos/bbolt@v1.3.7: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: go.etcd.io/bbolt
                but was required as: github.com/coreos/bbolt
```

Are there some ways to run omniledger or some other sharding blockchains? Eagery needed. Thanks a a lot.